# In MIT App inventor Application how to get the device id

Tags: android, app-inventor

Is there any way to get device Id using MIT App inventor?

I am using Activity starter from other stuff and setting properties like this:

- Action: `android.intent.action.ACTION_MAIN`
- Activity Class: `TelephonyManager`
- Activity Package: `android.telephony`

Is this the correct process for getting the device id?

Comment: I do not think you can get the device id from App Inventor. I vaguely remember from my days moderating the Google App Inventor forums you could not. I think there was a comment that you could write an app in Java and get it with App inventor Activity Starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Gary already mentioned, this is currently not possible with AI
**EDIT:** However, you can identify a user with OAuth, see an example here http://puravidaapps.com/taifunOA.php. The user can authorize the app to get his email address for identification.

**UPDATE**: now with the new Extension feature, you can use an extension to get this information, [see also my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37193572/1545993).