# Get unique android phone identification using MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

Using **MIT App Inventor 2**:

Is it possible to get some info from the phone to know who is it like:

- phone number or
- email address or
- IP address or
- device id or
- UUID or
- something else that I can use to identify that phone on my db?

I want to use some native component. (nothing like Identi or oauth)

Comment: @Tanis.7x The question is no duplicate. I'm not asking how to get that from java or android studio, I'm asking that on APP INVENTOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the IP address, you can use the `web` component and an API, see also https://www.google.com/search?q=get+ip+address+api
See also [How to work with the web component and an API](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/DvwZO3eDjHs/4m5fY9xhHd0J) by Stephen

To get phone number or email address or IP address or device id or UUID, blocks to do that are not available directly, but you could write your own **extension** and create a block yourself...

More information about how to create an extension see [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Ip2AX036d0U/5NJlAEbFCgAJ), 
however that will be more advanced and will require some Java skills...

Alternatively you can take a look at some of my already [available extensions](https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php)

- [Account Manager Extension](https://puravidaapps.com/accountmanager.php) to get some information about the user
- [Telephony Manager Extension](https://puravidaapps.com/telephonymanager.php) to get some information from the telephony manager.

The App Inventor Extensions are currently in testing. See the [announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Ip2AX036d0U/5NJlAEbFCgAJ) for more information and read the App Inventor Extensions document about how to use an App Inventor Extension.